# wp_pagenavi plugin with custom query not working in index.php - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress site where in my homepage I want to display the last 5 news, which are custom types. So I'm using the wp_pagenavi plugin but it doesn't work in 'index.php'. In www.mysite.com it displays the last 5 news and the pagination but when I try to move to the second (or another) page it doesn't display any news. For example, after clicking the page number 2 it redirects me to www.mysite.com/page/2/.

I have this code in index.php:

```
...
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$news = new WP_Query('post_type=news&cat=-5&paged='.$paged);

if ($news->have_posts()) :
?>
    <ul>
    <?php while ($news->have_posts()) : $news->the_post(); $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>
        <li>
        // Code for displaying news
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif;?>
<?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) : ?>
    <div class="navi"><?php wp_pagenavi(array( 'query' => $news )); ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved it.

I added the following code in functions.php:

```
function news_index($query) {
    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if ($query->is_home()) {
            $query->set('post_type', 'news');
            $query->set('cat', -5);
        }
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'news_index');
```

And in index.php I removed the custom query:

```
...
<?php
if ($have_posts()) :
?>
    <ul>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>
        <li>
        // Code for displaying news
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif;?>
<?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) : ?>
    <div class="navi"><?php wp_pagenavi(); ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
...
```